# Is there a museum anywhere at least partly about Rubik's Cube or Ernő Rubik?

Tags: museums, geek-travel, hungary, locate-this, budapest

Last year while I was in Budapest I had a realization that I was in the home of one of my favourite toys/puzzles/gadgets: [Rubik's Cube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube).

So I thought there must be some museum or display or official home of the Cube there where fans could make "pilgrimages" and learn about the history, maybe seeing prototypes and related inventions of [Ernő Rubik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ern%C5%91_Rubik) etc.

But hunting around and asking around turned up nothing at all! Can this be right that there is nothing to commemorate Rubik's Cube in the city where its inventor has always lived? Or is it merely little known, small, or not publicized in English?

Or maybe there is a smaller display in a larger museum or such? Maybe in a University? Maybe at the company headquarters?

Or maybe there is an Ernő Rubik or Rubik's Cube museum not in Hungary at all but on the other side of the world? Does anybody know of one anywhere?

Comment: maybe this event list helps you: http://www.worldcubeassociation.org/results/competitions.php

Comment: It seems speedcubing events are easier to find than "Cube Mecca" (-:

Comment: If you're looking for Rubik's Cube prototypes, you'll probably need to find your way back to the US. See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 10):

Have you had a look at the [Iparművészeti Múzeum](http://www.imm.hu/) (sorry, no english page...)? According to [http://budapestinterim.blogspot.com](http://budapestinterim.blogspot.com/2010/01/rubiks-cubes.html), there is (or was) an exhibition about Rubik cubes...

They have [a page about new acquisitions they made in 2009](http://www.imm.hu/hu/contents/125,%C3%9Aj+szerzem%C3%A9nyek) which very briefly mentions "a Rubik's collection".

[image: Iparművészeti Múzeum]

Comment: No I don't think I've heard of it, let me take a look! I know this building - took lots of photos of it last year but never went in. From memory it seemed closed when I was taking the photos. In fact even that article seems familiar like I might have looked it up once before...

Comment: I would love to hear from anyone that's been there, especially if you have some photos of the exhibits!

Answer (score 9):

Next year they'll start building a Rubik's Cube shaped museum that might open for the public in 2017 :)
http://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/museum/

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like this project never happened.

Answer (score 6):

The [Liberty Science Center](http://lsc.org/plan-your-visit/) in Jersey City, New Jersey, US, opened a Rubik's Cube exhibition named [Beyond Rubik's Cube](http://brc.lsc.org/) in [April 2014](http://www.nj.com/entertainment/index.ssf/2014/04/beyond_rubiks_cube_exhibit_opens_at_liberty_science_center.html). It remained there until November 2014, and then became a [traveling exhibition](http://lsc.org/see-whats-happening/current-exhibitions-and-experiences/cube/traveling-cube/) ([schedule available](http://brc.lsc.org/tour/)).

[Google collaborated with the museum](http://www.complex.com/style/2013/07/google-rubiks-cube-traveling-exhibition) in the exhibition's design. Among other things it includes a 10-foot (3 meter) tall Rubik's Cube that you can solve with your smartphone. It also includes the [original prototype Rubik's Cube](http://brc.lsc.org/invent/).

> Beyond Rubik's Cube features dozens of Ernő Rubik’s early puzzles, including the original Rubik’s Cube prototype. This is the first public display of these puzzles.

Ernő Rubik did [an interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jLR__L29SM) with the AP which references this exhibit. There is also a nice [video review](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbAYTfwomvk) of the exhibit from a Rubik's Cube fan.